# using BULK API to download AccountContactRelation

Tags: rest-api, bulk-api, bulk

Is it possible to do so?

using **BULK API** to download AccountContactRelation

I have a code already working and can download custom and standard objects, however when I try to download AccountContactRelation using **BULK API**, it gives "Bad Request"  simply at job creation.

Answer (score 0):

I got it working now, I just realized the REST api was hardcoded to use 30.0, and when changing it to API 40.0 I was able to download AccountContactRelation with BULK